# What is the frequency of the Sponsor Eagle?

Tags: pewdiepie-tuber-simulator

Is there a set frequency for the Sponsor eagle or is the time between 2 sponsor eagles random?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click the sponsor eagle, it will be something around 1 minute before it returns. If you miss it, it will come back after a minute or so.

Comment: So yes, in a way, it is

Comment: I have done some testing, and when I claim the reward from the Eagle, I actually got the next one within a minute or two.

Comment: @Auro ah, ok, then you have just answered your own question. Do some testing instead of just asking first, alright?

Comment: I wasn't the one asking the question, though. Yet I didn't want to steal your thunder.

Comment: @Auro also, whoops, I thought you asked the question for a second